# how do I see what certain docker daemon configurations are set to?

Tags: docker, configuration, daemon

I am having trouble finding out how to simply check what certain configs are set to for dockerd. `dockerd --help` shows all the possible options to use for setting configurations but how do I later go list what each one is currently set to?

For example, I know `--log-level` is set to 'info' by default and I also know how to change it, but how do I check what it is set to at any given time?

I try to use docker info or docker inspect to see some configurations but it doesn't give me all the info I need about the configuration of the daemon

Answer (score 0):

Docker picks the default conf from /etc/docker/daemon.json. cat this file for the default configurations set.
You can check https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd//#daemon-configuration-file for the config options.

Also you can run `docker info` for few of the configurations set.

Comment: Unfortunately /etc/docker/daemon.json does not exist unless I create my own daemon.json with configs in it. The only thing that is in /etc/docker is the key.json file. Thats why I am having trouble seeing what the default configs are cause there seems to be know config file anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer:

- create a dummy container using your docker daemon.
- `docker inspect dummy_container | grep -A 6 LogConfig`